# Connecting up washing machine

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine

I've connected up washing machines before but this time I'm confused. I have two lengths of pipe attached to the washing machine, one which is the input water pipe, and one which is the waste/output pipe.

On the wall the pipe at the top on the right has a washer covering the end and is ultimately connected to the cold tap on the sink,  I'm guessing that's where the input water comes from, but I can't see a tap connected to it (without removing the panel under the sink) and the sink adjacent works now. I'm concerned if I remove that water pressure will cover me with water! My only other thought would be the white tap under the sink?

Equally the one on the left is open so I'm guessing that's water coming out of the washing machine. Is that right? 
[image: washing machine space]

[image: adjacent sink]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two things you are looking at are valves with missing handles, one for hot water and one for cold water (clothes washers generally use both: cold for "darks", warm for "colors", and hot for "whites").

The larger black pipe visible on the far left side of your picture looks like a drain line suitable for the dirty-water discharge from your machine.

The hot and cold valves need to be replaced. The one on the right (usually cold) probably has that cap on it because it leaks by, and neither can be operated properly in their current state. Replacement will necessitate turning off the supply upstream, finding that upstream location would be your first objective here. Also you need to assess that drain line as it looks like it is being utilized for something else right now (note the corrugated tubing inserted into it).

Comment: One on the left ended up being cold and my washer only needs cold. Plumber came round and replace the valve and confirmed I can reuse the waste pipe as the other pipe comes from the combi boiler